# Run a vuejs code after all axios requests are completed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Here I need to run the **carResult** function only after all axios requests are completed. Adding it inside method2 success won't work since component is running the code twice. It would be great help if someone can help me with a vue code which works after all axios requests.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="el">
        <div>
            <p>Selected: {{ input.selected }}</p>
            <select2 :options="options" v-model="input.selected">
                <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
            </select2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Selected: {{ input.selected2 }}</p>
            <select2 :options="options2" v-model="input.selected2">
                <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
            </select2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="select2-template">
        <select>
        <slot></slot>
        </select>
    </script>
    <script src="http://themestarz.net/html/craigs/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
Vue.component('select2', {
    props: ['options', 'value'],
    template: '#select2-template',
    mounted: function () {
        var vm = this;
        $(this.$el)
                // init select2
                .select2({data: this.options})
                .val(this.value)
                .trigger('change')
                // emit event on change.
                .on('change', function () {
                    vm.$emit('input', this.value)
                })
    },
    watch: {
        options: function (options) {
            // update options
            $(this.$el).empty().select2({data: options})
        },
        value: function (value) {
            // update value
            $(this.$el)
                    .val(value)
                    .trigger('change')
        }
    },
    destroyed: function () {
        $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: {
        input: {
            selected2: "all",
            selected: "all"
        },
        options: [],
        options2: [],
        items: []
    },
    created: function () {
        this.mymethod();
    },
    watch: {
        input: {
            handler(newInput) {
                this.carResult(); 
            },
            deep: true
        },
        itemsArray() {
            this.setPages();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        mymethod: function () {
            var vm = this;
            axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        vm.options = [
                            {id: 0, text: 'All'},
                            {id: 1, text: 'Hello'},
                            {id: 2, text: 'World'},
                            {id: 3, text: 'Bye'}
                        ];
                        vm.input.selected = 2;
                        vm.method2();
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        },
        method2: function () {
            var vm = this;
            axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        vm.options2 = [
                            {id: 0, text: 'All'},
                            {id: 1, text: 'This'},
                            {id: 2, text: 'is'},
                            {id: 3, text: 'second'}
                        ];
                        vm.input.selected2 = 2;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        },
        carResult: function () {
            var vm = this;
            axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        vm.items = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        }
    }
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass all of your axios calls to `Promise.all()` which will resolve after all axios calls have been made.

```
Promise.all([axios.get(url1), axios.get(url2), axios.get(url3)])
  .then((allResults) => {
    console.log("All axios calls have been made!")
})
```

`Promise.all()` requires an array of promises as its argument and the `axios.get()` method returns a promise.

All returned values from `Promise.all()` will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all